# Validate greater than for not present field

Tags: laravel, validation

My validations looks like:

```
'from' => ['nullable', 'decimal', 'required_without:to'],
'to'  =>  ['nullable', 'decimal', 'required_without:from', 'gt:from'],
```

As you can see, one or both fields are required, but rule "greater than" return error when `form` field is null.

How to compare fields `to` to `form` when `form` sometimes isn't present in (or is null)?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `gt` rule conditionally with the `sometimes` method.

```php
$data = ['to' => 12.5];
$rules = [
    'from' => ['nullable', 'required_without:to'],
    'to' =>  ['nullable', 'required_without:from'],
];

$validator = validator($data, $rules);
$validator->sometimes('to', 'gt:from', function () use ($validator) {
    return array_key_exists('from', $validator->getData());
});
```

which would look like this inside a `FormRequest`

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'from' => ['nullable', 'required_without:to'],
        'to' =>  ['nullable', 'required_without:from'],
    ];
}

protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $validator = $this->getValidatorInstance();

    $validator->sometimes('to', 'gt:from', function () use ($validator) {
        $data = $validator->getData();

        return \array_key_exists('from', $data) && $data['from'] !== null;
    });
}
```

When sending data through a form, laravel will insert a null value if the input was not filled so the extra `&& $data['from'] !== null` must be added to the condition.

Comment: What you think with simplest way using `Rule::when`? But I don't know how to use it with array (`*`)

Comment: I don't think it would look simpler since it's conditional validation based on another input's value.